# What does .files[0] represent in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So when uploading an image via ajax and I come across something like this:

```
$("input#uploadedfile").on("change", function(){
   var file = this.files[0],
});
```

Assume #uploadedfile is a `file` type input, is `this.files[0]` just targeting the first file uploaded? Also is this jQuery doing the exact same thing?:

```
var file = $(this).get(0).files[0]
```

Comment: first file *to be* uploaded. Yes. Yes

Comment: Yeah my bad that's what I meant

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `files` property of an input element returns a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). Assuming `this` is an input element, `this.files[0]` returns a [`File` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) at the index `0`.

`$(this).get(0)` returns the first element of the jQuery object (remember that every jQuery object is also an array). So `$(this).get(0).files[0]` is another way of accessing the value of `this.files[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="list-group-item active"><h5>Feaured Image</h5></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="custom-file ">
                        <input type="file"  class="custom-file-input" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="thumbnail">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-thumbnail  text-center">
                    <img src="@if(isset($product)) {{asset('storage/'.$product->thumbnail)}} @else {{asset('images/no-thumbnail.jpeg')}} @endif" id="imgthumbnail" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
            </li>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#thumbnail').on('change', function() {
    var file = $(this).get(0).files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
    reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    var image = e.target.result;
$("#imgthumbnail").attr('src', image);
});
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to provide some explanation here Moazzam - running this would surely show what the code does, but I think some clarifying text would help as well.